# Testing class initializer using unittest in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I am using unittest module for writing tests.
I need to test initialization of the object inside a testcase using different inputs.
For this purpose I am importing the class inside setUp(). But when I try to use the class inside test_*() functions, I get this error - `NameError: name 'Example' is not defined`

Here is my code sample-

```
import unittest
class TestExample(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        import Example

    def test_sample_function(self):
        e = Example(1,2)
```

I know that I can simply import the class at top of the script. But I do not want to do that. I need to import it only during setup of the testscript.
Looking for some help here.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to import it in init. What do you think that will do differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import unittest
class TestExample(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        import Example
        self.Example = Example

    def test_sample_function(self):
        e = self.Example(1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to import the module in `setUp`. The module is still available globally in `sys.modules`, but you've only bound it to a *local* name that goes away after `setUp` returns. Just import it globally.

```
import unittest
import Example


class TestExample(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_sample_function(self):
        e = Example(1,2)
```